# Swiper.js событие onReachEnd срабатывает дважды

Tags: reactjs, react-hook, swiper.js

Использую свайпер для показа карточек постов и по идее, если потянуть слайды, находясь в конце списка, должна срабатывать функция, которая показывает спиннер и подтягивает новые поста. Все работает, но функция срабатывает дважды, если использовать юзСтейт.

[На английском стеке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76141460/function-fires-twice-on-event) мне помогли решить с помощью юзРеф, но мне это кажется костылем. Вопроса два:

1. Почему без юзРеф функция срабатывает дважды? Я пробовал делать рядом кнопку и вешать на нее то же событие, все отрабатывает один раз. Есть подозрение, что это нюанс самого свайпера. Когда я тяну за пределы списка, событие отрабатывает дважды - когда тяну и отпускаю, но это лишь догадка.
2. Можно ли решить, не прибегая к юзРеф?

   ```
   const PostList: FC = () => {
        const [postsData, setPostsData] = useState<TPost[] | undefined>();
        const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
        const [loadingMorePosts, setLoadingMorePosts] = useState(false);
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
        const [error, setError] = useState(false);
        const isShowMoreRunning = useRef(false);

        const showMore = () => { 
            setLoadingMorePosts(true);
            setPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1);
            console.log("SHOWMORE");
        }

        // const showMore = () => {
        //     if (!isShowMoreRunning.current) {
        //         isShowMoreRunning.current = true;
        //         setLoadingMorePosts(true);
        //         setPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1);
        //     }
        // };

        useEffect(() => {
            getPosts(page)
                .then(newPosts => newPosts.json() as Promise<TPostData>)
                .then(newPosts => {
                    setPostsData(prevState => [...(prevState ?? []), ...newPosts.posts]);
                    setLoadingMorePosts(false);
                    setLoading(false);
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    setError(true);
                    console.log(e.message);
                    setLoading(false);
                    setLoadingMorePosts(false);
                })
        }, [page]);

        // useEffect(() => {
        //     isShowMoreRunning.current = false;
        // }, [postsData]);

        if (loading) return <Spinner />;

        return (
            <div className="post-list">
                <div className="post-list__menu">
                    <div className="post-list__menu-left">
                        <span>user stories</span>
                        <span className='disabled'>last change<span className='sticker'>soon</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <AddStoryModal />
                </div>
                <div className='post-list__postitem-view'>
                    <Swiper
                        spaceBetween={10}
                        slidesPerView={"auto"}
                        touchMoveStopPropagation={true}
                        onReachEnd={showMore}
                        freeMode={{
                            enabled: true,
                            sticky: false,
                            momentumRatio: 0.4
                        }}
                        mousewheel={{
                            forceToAxis: false,
                            sensitivity: 1,
                            releaseOnEdges: true,
                          }}
                          modules={[Mousewheel, FreeMode]}
                        >
                        {error ? <ErrorSign /> : postsData?.map((post: TPost) => {
                            return <SwiperSlide key={post.id}>
                                <PostItem key={post.id} title={post.title} body={post.body} userId={post.userId} id={post.id} />
                            </SwiperSlide>
                        })}
                        {loadingMorePosts && <SwiperSlide className='post-item-spinner' key={"spinner"}><Spinner loadingMorePosts={loadingMorePosts} /></SwiperSlide>}
                    </Swiper>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };

    export default PostList;
   ```